# Japanese Format

Tags: php, wordpress, converters, taxonomy

In WordPress When I read a tag from taxonomy by Japanese, it like this '日本語' but this is the result `%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e`. I have compared it with right text. It become true.

```
if(strcmp($row[$header][$i]['slug'], '日本語'))
```

I would like to write csv file which using Japanese Characters . how could I convert `%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e` to '日本語'.

Comment: How exactly are you "reading a tag from taxonomy"? Show you code.

Comment: I use $string = $row[$header][$i]['slug']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [urldecode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to invert:

```
$string = urldecode('%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e'); // Converts to 日本語
```

[SEE DEMO.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a38580be3458b6a6510c903e20ed66982228f44)

You can use [urlencode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) method to compare and [strcasecmp](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) for case-insensitive comparision:

```
if( strcasecmp($row[$header][$i]['slug'], urlencode('日本語')) )
```

[SEE DEMO.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e03e8622ec1fe1ff28136f3b475dd7dbb501a464)